# OData HTTP400 Timeout Error

Tags: sql-server, timeout, odata, http-status-code-400

This is one of the most bizarre problems I've come across since I started using OData for my mobile apps. The OData server I've developed is backed by SQL Express 2008 and this combination has been installed on 50 different servers and/or PCs over the last 15 months. All 50 servers have been running stable with consistent function for large amounts of data.

A couple of days ago one of my clients contacted me indicating that my client app (running on iOS7) was having an odd error come up when POSTing data to their server. The error had an HTTP code of 400 and the error text is "The operation couldn't be completed. (Timeout error 400.)". My first question is: why is a timeout error coming back with a 400 code? Generally when I get timeouts (due to firewall, etc) they're in the 100x range. There is no indication in the event logs on the server of ANY problems occurring. My own logs (stored in the SQL database) show no error (which is odd because I'm using the generic exception catching method in my OData service to log any problems). I haven't got to the step of adding logging of all requests as yet.

The error is only being raised when posting one particular set of data. All other posts from the device are functioning perfectly. I got the client to re-install the app (deleting all data) and then to download the data set that was causing the error. The download worked fine. We began making changes to the data to replicate what the data looked like when the error occurred in incremental changes, posting the change to the server and observing the result. Most of the incremental changes work fine but certain combinations cause the error to occur. One of the increments involves a large volume of changes and that posts fine, but subsequent alteration of any of the objects (sometimes altering as little as 6 characters in a text field) cause the error to occur. And yet in some circumstances altering objects that have already been posted to the server works without a problem.

I wiped the service components from the server and undertook a fresh install. I shifted TCP ports in case 443 had another listener causing problems. I reset the server. None of these change the behaviour of the error.

My last ditch solution is to completely re-install IIS and .NET Framework but I'd obviously like to avoid this as it's not my server... The server is overseas from my current location so debugging isn't really an option. Hoping someone has an idea as to what I can do diagnostically to try and determine the source of this bizarre 'gremlin'.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but I can tell you not to despair; there's an explanation for [everything](http://mina.naguib.ca/blog/2012/10/22/the-little-ssh-that-sometimes-couldnt.html) (your problem seems so similar and so different). The fact that you're not seeing anything in any of your logs suggest that this is pretty low-level, yet the fact that you get an HTTP error from a remote device suggests it's high-level. Extremely long shot: Any router doing DPI on the path? Any HTTP proxy or reverse-proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a more thorough traffic analysis using a tool like Fiddler?  The "timeout" error does indeed seem odd and what stood from you post was that your server was "overseas".  Could there be something with the "times" that are being used/generated, e.g. server time, local time, etc?

Just to confirm, the "same" exact set of data always fails?  Can you replicate this via a remote debugger or via localhost?  If so, can you turn on "verbose errors"?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. The comment regarding the server being OS was that it's overseas from where I am. The client app and server are co-located on the same WiFi network.

Comment: I've used Fiddler2 for development but have only ever had success capturing outbound packets and their responses. Is there a good tutorial on 'how to setup fiddler to capture inbound packets'?